# DIV moves when it has children elements

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have two divs:

```
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="box">
Test
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.box{
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Why aren't both divs on the same Y position?

Comment: You mean, on overlaying each other?

Comment: Put text in both boxes, they'll line up then :-)

Comment: No, the right one is on another height (position, not size) than the other

Comment: @davvy yes I could do that, but why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align: top;` to make `inline-block` align on top. The default value is `baseline` and it is moved since one block has text and the other doesn't. Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

```
.box{
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Good luck :)